# Functional Approach: Merge Two Arrays and Return a Tuple with common objects

Tags: arrays, swift, functional-programming

I need A functional Approach to this situation: I have two arrays of the same Object Type and I need create a function that returns a tuple array of these objects with the same ID.

Here my **imperative implementation**:

```
  func filterById(personArray : [Person], anotherPersonArray : [Person]) -> [(Person,Person)]{
    var ret = [(Person,Person)]()
    for person in personArray{
        for person2 in anotherPersonArray{
            if person.id?.intValue == person2.id?.intValue{
                ret.append(person,person2)
            }

        }

    }
    return ret
```

And now my functional Attempt to achieve this, but it **always returns an Empty Array**

```
return Array(zip(personArray,anotherPersonArray)).filter
                                               {$0.id?.intValue == $1.id?.intValue}}}
```

How can I do a Functional Approach to this?

Comment: hey, I have no knowledge of swift but this is how you'd do it in scala using the for comprehension, maybe swift has something similar. http://goo.gl/6yP9cZ

Comment: what you need to do is a cartesian product between the lists and pick only the ones for which the id's are the same

Comment: That looks a lot like your imperative implementation. But I don't know of a function to take 2 lists and create a cartesian product out of them.

Answer (score 2):

You can basically do what @toskv said in his comment: cartesian product and then filter by the same id's. You can do it like this:

```
func filterById(a : [Person], b : [Person]) -> [(Person, Person)] {
    let lazyCartProd = a.lazy.map{ p in
        b.lazy.map{ (p, $0) }
    }.flatten()

    let lazySame = lazyCartProd.filter{ $0.id == $1.id }

    return Array(lazySame)
}
```

Note that there is no intermediate array created because it's lazy. You could also pack this into one statement, but I didn't because of clarity.

Fun thing: `lazySame` is of type:

```
LazyFilterCollection<FlattenBidirectionalCollection<LazyMapCollection<Array<Person>, LazyMapCollection<Array<Person>, (Person, Person)>>>>
```

That's why type inference is cool :D

Probably you shouldn't use array's at all though, if you make your `Person` type conform to `Hashable`, you can put it in a `Set` and use the much more efficient methods like `intersect`, `contains`, `union`, etc. whose complexity is about `n` times better than if you'd use an array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return personArray.map {
    p -> [(Person, Person)] in
    anotherPersonArray
        .filter { $0.id == p.id }
        .map { (p, $0) }
}.flatMap { $0 }
```

I assume that `id` is unique within each array. [SwiftStub](http://swiftstub.com/817379324/?v=beta).